How is Trainer EXP caluculated in Magikarp Jump?
When you retire a Magikarp in Magikarp Jump, your trainer gains a certain amount of experience points that contribute toward your next trainer level. How are these trainer points calculated each time you retire a Magikarp? What is the list of factors that contribute?
